# Python/SciPy Filtering With Time Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, filter, scipy

Apologies up front if this is obvious, I'm new to Python and I haven't seen anywhere that answers what I'm struggling with.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17884962/3303504) Dave gives the following code example for how to implement a filter in SciPy:

```
# spell out the args that were passed to the Matlab function
N = 10
Fc = 40
Fs = 1600
# provide them to firwin
h = scipy.signal.firwin(numtaps=N, cutoff=40, nyq=Fs/2)
# 'x' is the time-series data you are filtering
y = scipy.signal.lfilter(h, 1.0, x)
```

What I don't understand is how to do this whilst explicitly providing the timestamp data with the signal values. My data isn't collected in perfect time steps and so filtering without that information feels like garbage in garbage out.

Example data:

```
#Time    ,  Value
[0.004000,  0.023880] # diffT = 0
[0.012000,  0.022180] # diffT = 8
[0.028000,  0.023370] # diffT = 16
[0.043000,  0.022130] # diffT = 15
[0.053000,  0.022300] # diffT = 10
[0.072000,  0.022410] # diffT = 19
[0.079000,  0.022350] # diffT = 7
```

If its of any help, I'm needing to perform low pass and high pass filtering only, but would need to play around with the parameters to find the best filter coefficients.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You are right in assuming that filtering to non-uniformly sampled signals results in garbage. These functions really only work with uniform steps, so the most straight-forward approach is to bring the data into a form with uniform time steps. The terms *interpolation* and *resampling* come to mind...